# On AIX machine can I use libraries(both static and dynamic) compiled with xLC and use them with gcc compiler?

Tags: gcc, aix, xlc

My C static and dynamic libraries are compiled with xLC compiler. Is it possible to use those libraries in some program and use gcc as compiler on AIX? Or Is it necessary to use xLC only as the compiler for later part also?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Definitely.  gcc does not come with a libc (as a trivial example) but can use printf, etc.

You are actually asking about the "ABI"  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface  For a particular platform, compilers conform to that particular "ABI".